# Facebook Social Share dialog button link in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a hard time configuring the social sharing dialog for my project. I have made a few changes to the direct link to support my posts page.

Share dialog code:

```
<%= link_to('Share on Facebook', 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=*********&display=popup&href=https://xxx&name=<%= @community.title %>&description=<%= @community.content %>&redirect_uri=<%= community_path(@community) %>',:target => :blank) %>
```

Where community are basically my posts. This is generating an error unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'.

Appreciate any help, either improving the original link or anything else.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Facebook, it is a simple syntax error in your code. Tags related to Facebook removed.

Comment: Hey @CBroe, if you can see the problem with his code, any reason why you wouldn't point it out to the OP? Just saying...

Comment: @ardochhigh just because I can tell what the problem is _not_ about, doesn't mean I am familiar with the specifics of the language OP is using. And reading up on the basic syntax to achieve the desired output here, I'll leave up to the one using it.

Comment: Maybe give a new SO user some guidance ... and a break? None of us are experts at everything. Peace brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am googling easiest way to  add social links from web sites, including the Facebook share button is using the gem `'social-share-button'`

refer the link

(https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button)

Comment: I do not want to use a gem. I have seen the gem but it doesn't match my expectations. So you see anything wrong with the link above?

Comment: ok without gem you have to use `Dialog API`  refer this link (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) it should help you

Comment: I have used it but it doesn't work with rails dynamic tags.

Comment: try this (http://launchware.com/articles/accessible-facebook-dialogs-and-feed-posting-with-rails)